# How can I write float value in python that can be read natively in Java?

Tags: java, python

How can I write float value to file in python so that it can be later read in Java with `ObjectInputStream#readFloat`?

I need high read performance, so I'd like to avoid parsing the float from String.

Comment: For the non-Java-guys, could you elaborate on the format `ObjectInputStream#readFloat` expects? Is it the bits of an IEEE floating point number, verbatim without any metadata, or some specific serialization protocol? In the latter case, it may be easier to agree on the former instead.

Comment: @delnan Not a complete answer but as far as I know, floats in Java are IEEE-754 compatible 32-bit floating point numbers. Also going by the max value for Java float ( (2-2^-23)·2^127 ) it would be the *single precision* or *binary32* version of the IEEE-754 floats.

Comment: Have you tried looking into Jython? Jython is an implementation of Python that runs on the JVM, and it has support for interacting with Java types. You could even instantiate an ObjectInputStream object from within a python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `struct` module ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html)), specifying the data as a `f`loat.

Comment: Although, in any application that's so performance-critical that you care about the tiny amount of time used to parse a float when you already have to spend time to read it out of a file (I/O is usually the bottleneck in these things), you probably should be trying very hard to work around the need for floating-point types in the first place. Consider using a fixed-point arithmetic library.

Comment: Thanks, IO is not the bottleneck here, I measured that. Perhaps the bigger reason why I don't want to encode the float to String is that it's not space efficient (the float data will be bundled into Android package so I'm trying not to make it too big).